# Github repo appears empty, but cloning it shows files

Tags: git, github

I forked a repository on github (https://github.com/VimEz/ShowMarks -> https://github.com/mikeage/ShowMarks) and pushed two changes. For some reason, when I browse the latest commit (or the master branch) via the github web UI, it seems to be totally empty, though a fresh clone of the repo shows that there are, in fact, all the files present.

I'm a bit of a git newbie, and have absolutely no idea what could have happened here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your latest checkin of .gitignore has rules which are too broad and this is causing GitHub to ignore all your files when listing them.

Take a look at the files for your first commit via the Browse Code link: https://github.com/mikeage/ShowMarks/tree/9dbc5f02730725a6992eec8bf86fea257cec858c

Then take a look at the files for your second commit via the Browse Code link:
https://github.com/mikeage/ShowMarks/tree/5aea9c7879072001dc01d707734a252c3efbf297

You will see that your second commit changed the listing substantially.

To fix this, I'd suggest narrowing down your .gitignore so that it only contains:

```
*.swo
*.swp
tags
```

By the way, I wrote a blog post about .gitignore files if you want to do further reading about it: http://www.luisdelarosa.com/2011/05/16/what-to-put-in-your-gitignore/

Comment: I didn't mean to add .gitignore itself to .gitignore, but I do want to keep *~.

I tried clearing both new lines; it worked. Then I added them back in. It worked again.

I'm not sure what the problem was, but I set .gitignore the way I wanted, and now it seems to be working just fine.